# insufficientFilePermissions error when try to export GDrive workspace files

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

**Encountered insufficientFilePermissions error when try to export GDrive workspace files.**

**Error:**

```
googleapiclient.http:Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "insufficientFilePermissions"

<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{File_ID}/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation&alt=media returned "
The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{
'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.', 
'domain': 'global', 
'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions'
}]">
```

I am using **python** code found at [Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#export_document_content)

To test the code, I configured service_account on my GDrive account. I am able to download the Google workspace files and it is working fine. But, the same code is throwing above mentioned error for customer GDrive. I configured service_account correctly as able to download rest of the GDrive files other than worksapce.

Sharing, the GDrive workspace file structure is

```
{
    'kind': 'drive#file',
    'copyRequiresWriterPermission': False,
    'writersCanShare': True,
    'viewedByMe': True,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation',
    'exportLinks': {
        'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id={file_id}&exportFormat=odp',
        'application/pdf': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id={file_id}&exportFormat=pdf',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id={file_id}&exportFormat=pptx',
        'text/plain': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id={file_id}&exportFormat=txt'
    },
    'parents': ['root'],
    'thumbnailLink': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id={file_id}&v=2&s=AMedNnoAAAAAZH2QVm6sssfJMwvO4_wZtTxvWk9-VGZP&sz=s220',
    'iconLink': 'https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.presentation',
    'shared': False,
    'lastModifyingUser': {
        'displayName': '{user_name}',
        'kind': 'drive#user',
        'me': True,
        'permissionId': '{permissionId}',
        'emailAddress': '{email_id}'
    },
    'owners': [{
        'displayName': '{user_name}',
        'kind': 'drive#user',
        'me': True,
        'permissionId': '{permissionId}',
        'emailAddress': '{email_id}'
    }],
    'webViewLink': 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{file_id}/edit?usp=drivesdk',
    'viewersCanCopyContent': True,
    'permissions': [{
        'id': '{permissionId}',
        'displayName': '{user_name}',
        'type': 'user',
        'kind': 'drive#permission',
        'emailAddress': '{email_id}',
        'role': 'owner',
        'deleted': False,
        'pendingOwner': False
    }],
    'hasThumbnail': True,
    'spaces': ['drive'],
    'id': '{file_id}',
    'name': '{file name}',
    'starred': False,
    'trashed': False,
    'explicitlyTrashed': False,
    'createdTime': '2022-02-22T04:05:47.677Z',
    'modifiedTime': '2022-02-22T04:05:51.475Z',
    'modifiedByMeTime': '2022-02-22T04:05:51.475Z',
    'viewedByMeTime': '2022-02-22T04:05:51.475Z',
    'quotaBytesUsed': '0',
    'version': '275',
    'ownedByMe': True,
    'isAppAuthorized': False,
    'capabilities': {
        'canChangeViewersCanCopyContent': True,
        'canEdit': True,
        'canCopy': True,
        'canComment': True,
        'canAddChildren': False,
        'canDelete': True,
        'canDownload': True,
        'canListChildren': False,
        'canRemoveChildren': False,
        'canRename': True,
        'canTrash': True,
        'canReadRevisions': True,
        'canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission': True,
        'canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive': True,
        'canUntrash': True,
        'canModifyContent': True,
        'canMoveItemOutOfDrive': True,
        'canAddMyDriveParent': False,
        'canRemoveMyDriveParent': True,
        'canMoveItemWithinDrive': True,
        'canShare': True,
        'canMoveChildrenWithinDrive': False,
        'canModifyContentRestriction': True,
        'canChangeSecurityUpdateEnabled': False,
        'canAcceptOwnership': False,
        'canReadLabels': True,
        'canModifyLabels': True
    },
    'thumbnailVersion': '2',
    'modifiedByMe': True,
    'permissionIds': ['{permissionId}'],
    'linkShareMetadata': {
        'securityUpdateEligible': False,
        'securityUpdateEnabled': True
    }
```

Comment: please include your code

Answer (score 2):

> The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

Means exactly that the user that you are authencating with does not have permission to access the file.   You are using a service account so you have two options.

One open the service account file find the service account email address. Its the only one with a @ in it go to google drive web app and share a directory with the service account like you would any other user.

The second option because you are using google workspace this is probably the best option would be to have the admin of your workspace domain to configure domain wide delegation for your service account. this will grant the service account access to impersonate any user on the workspace domain.  YOu can then specify which user you want to impersonate in your code.

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
    scopes=SCOPES)

credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)
```

Note im going to see about contacting the team about the link you posted.  Seams strange how they have documented workspace drive auth to me.

Comment: Thank you for you response, so coming to secound solution you have suggested is impliment by me already but error still same for the cilent which i am tested.
try:
            credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
except FileNotFoundError:
            logging.error("Credentials not found")
            return returnfunction(404,1,"Credentials not found")
subject = args.useriddelegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(subject)
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)

Comment: I refer this document for second solution that you have suggested: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python

Comment: Failed to understand the same code and service_account configuration, I am able to download normal files (pdf, mp4 and jpeg) but failed to download google workspace files (doc, sheet and presentation) own by the same user.

Comment: google doc mine types need to be exported its a different method

Comment: Google workspace file mime convertion are already handled in my code. Let me explain my problem again. The code is running fine for my GDrive account. It is able to download workspace files(covert into proper mime format) and rugular files. But the same code failed to download the workspace files from other GDrive account but able to download the ragular files. While downloading it throw insufficient permission.

Comment: The code you linked is only for export so it will only work with drive mime types as it exports for example sheets files to xls files.   Something like an exe or a zip it wont be able to download as that code is not designed to download binary files.